# how to get a div relative to another div but with z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

hello all please look at the image below
[image]

The problem that i am having is very simple and common i am having div 1, div2 and div3 in a loop div 1 and div 2 is visible but divs 3 are hidden all the div with no 3 are hidden and it shows when on clicked on div2 everything is great till now the issue what i am havving is that i want something like this.

[image]

please ignore the colors 
what i want is that div3 should adjust it self to the best availabe position and space if there is no space in the left side get to the right or top or bottom it should auto adjust just like title of any thing in default settings.

what i have tried to do is something like

```
  <div> // div1
     <div> //div 2
         <div class='div3'> //div 3
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
    .div3 {position:absolute;right:0px;}
```

please tell me something about this

Comment: can you setup a demo on jsfiddle or codepen in order to help you :) . Did you consider the use of absolute positionning ? For the "best" position (right/left), javascript will be needed.

Comment: For the "best" position (right/left), javascript will be needed - i am ok with JS ..

Comment: when you set up working demo (as @ GCyrillus mentioned) people can help you much easier and quicker

Comment: ok i try and then update you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the problem your experiencing right?
They gray tiles are behind the black ones take a look:

```css
.div1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #222;
}
.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ee2;
  top: 60%;
  left: 60%;
}
.div3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: gray;
  left: 100%;
  top: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
</div>

<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
</div>
```

The solution is pretty simple: 
If you add a z-index of more then 1 its fixed.
I added a z-index of 5.

```css
.div1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #222;
}
.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ee2;
  top: 60%;
  left: 60%;
}
.div3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: gray;
  left: 100%;
  top: 80%;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
</div>

<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: no no the issue is that the gray tiles should arrange themselves in the best possible was like if there is no space in the right side it should come to the left or top .